# update sql column using a hyperlink in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, hyperlink, sql-update

I have an sql datasource inner joined with 2 tables `(product table[product quantity column]` and `customer product table[ProductID,CustomerID,TotalProducts, UpdatedProducts])`

Currently i have this code behind using a sql button:

```
using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
        {
            scn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update o set o.Updatedproduct = p.ProductQuantity - o.Totalproduct from CustomerProducts o inner join Products p on o.ProductID = p.ProductID", scn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

though it works fine and upon button click, it updates all the fields in the `updated products column` but what i want to do is to do the same functionality but with a hyperlink. Also, it will only update a specific field. Here is an image to make it clearer:

[image]

UPDATE:
so far i got this.
html:

```
   <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" CommandName="UpdateProduct" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerID")+","+ Eval("ProductID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

code behind:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Approve")
        {
            using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
            {
                scn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update o set o.Updatedproduct = p.ProductQuantity - o.Totalproduct from CustomerProducts o inner join Products p on o.ProductID = p.ProductID WHERE WHERE ProductID=@ProductID", scn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", ID);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

nothings happening here

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete example.Hope it helps you:

**.ASPX:**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" CommandName="UpdateProduct" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerID")+","+ Eval("ProductID") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
  public partial class GridViewRowCommandExample : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                var p1 = new Product { CustomerID = 1, ProductID = 11 };
                var p2 = new Product { CustomerID = 2, ProductID = 22 };

                GridView1.DataSource = new List<Product> { p1, p2 };
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "UpdateProduct")
            {
                string[] parameters = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(',');
                int customerID = Int32.Parse(parameters[0]);
                int productID = Int32.Parse(parameters[1]);
                //Now that you know which row to update run the SQL update statement 
            }
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: thank you sir. would you mind checking my update sir?

Comment: Firstly don't use button field,use template and a link button because you need to specify the CommandArgument property and populate this property with the id of the record you need to update.Look how I've done it.Secondly you are specifying a parameter called @ProductID but your SqlCommand uses Id, that's why you get the error.You need to make sure the parameter names match

Comment: i used item template. now its doing nothing sir?

Comment: Please change it to WHERE ProductID=@ProductID

Comment: Because CommandName parameters don't match.One is called "Approve" and the one in the .aspx is called CommandName="UpdateProduct".Place a break point inside RowCommand and inspect the e.CommandName property

Comment: already changed it sir. gives me another error `Ambiguous column name 'ProductID'.`

Comment: do i need this sir? `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerID")+","+ Eval("ProductID") %>' />`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115591/discussion-between-denis-wessels-and-reine-viray).

Answer (score 0):

First put a button field with "ButtonFieldName" in GridView control and then try GridView Control's RowCommand event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ButtonFieldName")
    {
       // Your Logic goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. how can i make it update a specific row? for example Customer ID 10?